# Cannot append objects to a list

Tags: python, list, class, object

I'm having some troubles with my code. This is a budget app in which you can add categories and for every category you can deposit/withdraw money. The problem is that I have to save all the transactions in the format {"amount": x, "description":y} and to do this I create an object of class Amount which is defined in the code, but when I try to append the new Amount object to the list every single element of this list changes to the last object. I understood that when I add an object, all the other elements in the list refer to the same object, and that's probably the problem, but I cannot solve this. Can you help me? Thank you very much
(This bug happens in the methods deposit and withdraw)

```
class Amount:
    
    tot={"amount":0,"description":""}

    def __init__(self,am,descr=""):
        self.tot["amount"]=am
        self.tot["description"]=descr
    
    def getTot(self):
        return self.tot


class Category:

    title=""
    deposit_list=list()
    balance=0

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.title=name
    
    def __str__(self):
        final_string=""
        length=int((30-len(self.title))/2)

        for i in range(0,length):
            final_string+="*"

        final_string+=self.title
        for i in range(0,length):
            final_string+="*"

        final_string+="\n"

        for x in self.deposit_list:
            y=x.getTot()["description"]
            y=y[0:23]
            z=float(x.getTot()["amount"])

            final_string+=y
            l=len(y)
            if l<23:
                for i in range(l,23):
                    final_string+=" "
            
            z=str(z)
            l=len(z)
            if l<7:
                for i in range(l,7):
                    final_string+=" "
            final_string+=z
            final_string+="\n"
        final_string+="Total: "
        final_string+=str(self.balance)

        return final_string

    def get_balance(self):
        return self.balance
    
    def getTitle(self):
        return self.title
        
    def deposit(self,amount,description=""):
        
        if description!="":
            description=str(description)
        
        dep=Amount(amount,description)
        self.deposit_list.append(dep)
        self.balance+=dep.getTot()["amount"]
        
    
    def withdraw(self,amount,description=""):
        
        if description!="":
            description=str(description)
        
        wd=Amount(-1*amount,description)

        if self.check_funds(amount):
            self.deposit_list.append(wd)
            self.balance+=wd.getTot()["amount"]
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def transfer(self,amount,dest):
        descr_dest="Transfer from "
        descr_dest+=self.getTitle()
        descr_src="Transfer to "
        descr_src+=dest.getTitle()
        if self.withdraw(amount,descr_src)==True:
            dest.deposit(amount,descr_dest)
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def check_funds(self,amount):
        if amount>self.balance:
            return False
        else:
            return True

def create_spend_chart(categories):
    return
```

Edit:
I'm sorry, here is a test you can run

```
import budget
from unittest import main

food = budget.Category("Food")
food.deposit(1000, "initial deposit")
food.withdraw(10.15, "groceries")
food.withdraw(15.89, "restaurant and more food for dessert")
clothing = budget.Category("Clothing")
food.transfer(50, clothing)

print(food)
```

It should print this:

```
*************Food*************
initial deposit        1000.00
groceries               -10.15
restaurant and more foo -15.89
Transfer to Clothing    -50.00
Total: 923.96
```

I also have to say that it should print only the first 23 characters of the description, but this shouldn't be important for the question.
@frno that was an attempt to avoid the problem described in the question, I edited the code as it was before that update
Thank you!

Comment: Your `deposit_list` is a class variable, not an instance variable. Same with `Amount.tot`. But please, provide a [mcve]

Comment: Can you specify how you use the objects? Please provide some test code we can run, the class definitions aren't enough.

Comment: What @juanpa.arrivillaga said. Plus as a side note, Why would you defense copy new instances of Amount you just created ?

Comment: I edited the question with a test you can run. @juanpa.arrivillaga ok, I made this mistake because in Java everything written there is an attribute of every object created of that class. How can I solve this? I'm new to Python and I still have to understand this details. Thank you!

Comment: Python != Java. You probably should read the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html You need to assign to the instance, i.e. `self.attribute = whatever`, generally inside `__init__`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Surely I will. Thank you! It works, that was the problem. Also thanks to frno and alec_djinn!